# First order hidden Markov model with Viterbi algorithm in Java

Tags: java, algorithm, statistics, bioinformatics, markov-chain

## Introduction

A first order HMM (hidden Markov model) is a tuple \$(H, \Sigma, T, E, \mathbb{P})\$, where \$H = \{1, \ldots, \vert H \vert\}\$ is the set of hidden states, \$\Sigma\$ is the set of symbols, \$T \subseteq H \times H\$ is the set of transitions, \$E \subseteq H \times \Sigma\$ is the set of emissions, and \$\mathbb{P}\$ is the probability function for elements of \$T\$ and \$E\$, satisfying the following conditions:

1. There is a single *start state* \$h_{\texttt{start}} \in H\$ with no incoming transitions \$(h, h_{\texttt{start}}) \in T\$, and no emissions.
2. There is a single *end state* \$h_{\texttt{end}} \in H\$ with no out-going transitions \$(h_{\texttt{end}}, h) \in H\$, and no emissions.
3. Let \$\mathbb{P}(h \, \vert \, h^\prime)\$ denote the probability for the transition \$(h^\prime, h) \in T\$, and let \$\mathbb{P}(c \, \vert \, h)\$ denote the probability of an emission \$(h, c) \in E\$, for \$h^\prime, h \in H\$ and \$c \in \Sigma\$. It must hold that
   $$
   \sum_{h \in H} \mathbb{P}(h \, \vert \, h^\prime) = 1, \text{ for all } h^\prime \in H \setminus \{ h_{\texttt{end}} \},
   $$
   and
   $$\sum_{c \in \Sigma} \mathbb{P}(c \, \vert \, h) = 1, \text{ for all } h \in H \setminus \{ h_{\texttt{start}}, h_{\texttt{end}} \}.$$

A *path through an HMM* is a sequence \$P\$ of hidden states \$P=p_0p_1 \cdots p_n p_{n+1}\$, where \$(p_i, p_{i + 1}) \in T\$, for each \$i \in \{ 0, \ldots, n \}. \$ The *joint probability* of \$P\$ and a sequence \$S = s_1 s_2 \cdots s_n\$, with each \$s_i \in \Sigma,\$ is
$$
\mathbb{P}(P, S) = \prod_{i = 0}^n \mathbb{P}(p_{i + 1} \, \vert \,  p_i) \prod_{i = 1}^n \mathbb{P}(s_i \, \vert \, p_i). 
$$
Also, we define \$\mathcal{P}(n)\$ as the set of all paths \$p_0 p_1 \cdots p_{n + 1}\$ through the HMM, of length \$n + 2\$, such that \$p_0 = h_{\texttt{start}}\$ and \$p_{n + 1} = h_{\texttt{end}}.\$

We need to solve two problems here. First, we need to construct the most probable path \$P^{\star}\$ that accords the input sequence \$S\$:
$$
P^\star = \arg \max_{P \in \mathcal{P}(n)} \mathbb{P}(P, 
S).
$$
Second, we want to generate all the sequence \$S\$ according state paths and return the sum of all state path probabilities:
$$
\mathbb{P}(S)  = \sum_{P \in \mathcal{P}(n)} \mathbb{P}(P, S).
$$

## Code

(The entire repository is in [**HiddenMarkovModel.java**](https://github.com/coderodde/HiddenMarkovModel.java).)

**`com.github.coderodde.hmm.HiddenMarkovModel.java:`**

```
package com.github.coderodde.hmm;

import java.util.ArrayDeque;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Deque;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Set;

/**
 * This class implements an HMM (hidden Markov model).
 */
public final class HiddenMarkovModel {
    
    /**
     * Used to denote the Viterbi matrix cells that are not yet computed.
     */
    private static final double UNSET_PROBABILITY = -1.0;
    
    /**
     * The start state of the process.
     */
    private final HiddenMarkovModelState startState;
    
    /**
     * The end state of the process.
     */
    private final HiddenMarkovModelState endState;
    
    private final Random random;
    
    public HiddenMarkovModel(HiddenMarkovModelState startState,
                             HiddenMarkovModelState endState,
                             Random random) {
        
        this.startState = startState;
        this.endState = endState;
        this.random = random;
    }
    
    public static double sumPathProbabilities(
            List<HiddenMarkovModelStatePath> paths) {
        
        double psum = 0.0;
        
        for (HiddenMarkovModelStatePath path : paths) {
            psum += path.getProbability();
        }
        
        return psum;
    }
    
    /**
     * Performs a brute-force computation of the list of all possible paths in
     * this HMM.
     * 
     * @param sequence the target text.
     * @return the list of sequences, sorted from most probable to the most
     *         improbable.
     */
    public List<HiddenMarkovModelStatePath> 
        computeAllStatePaths(String sequence) {
            
        int expectedStatePathSize = sequence.length() + 2;
        
        List<List<HiddenMarkovModelState>> statePaths = new ArrayList<>();
        List<HiddenMarkovModelState> currentPath = new ArrayList<>();
        
        // BEGIN: Do the search:
        currentPath.add(startState);
        
        depthFirstSearchImpl(statePaths, 
                             currentPath,
                             expectedStatePathSize, 
                             startState);
        
        // END: Searching done.
        
        // Construct the sequences:
        List<HiddenMarkovModelStatePath> sequenceList = 
                new ArrayList<>(statePaths.size());
        
        for (List<HiddenMarkovModelState> statePath : statePaths) {
            sequenceList.add(
                    new HiddenMarkovModelStatePath(
                            statePath, 
                            sequence,
                            this));
        }
        
        // Put into descending order by probabilities:
        Collections.sort(sequenceList);
        Collections.reverse(sequenceList);
        
        return sequenceList;
    }
        
    /**
     * Returns the most probable state path for the input sequence using the 
     * <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viterbi_algorithm">
     * Viterbi algorithm.</a>
     * 
     * @param sequence the target sequence.
     * @return the state path.
     */
    public HiddenMarkovModelStatePath runViterbiAlgorithm(String sequence) {
        
        // Get all the states reachable from the start state:
        Set<HiddenMarkovModelState> graph = computeAllStates();
        
        if (!graph.contains(endState)) {
            // End state unreachable. Abort.
            throw new IllegalStateException("End state is unreachable.");
        }
        
        // Maps the column index to the corresponding state:
        Map<Integer, HiddenMarkovModelState> stateMap = 
                new HashMap<>(graph.size());
        
        // Maps the state to the corresponding column index:
        Map<HiddenMarkovModelState, Integer> inverseStateMap = 
                new HashMap<>(graph.size());
        
        // Initialize maps for start and end states:
        stateMap.put(0, startState);
        stateMap.put(graph.size() - 1, endState);
        
        inverseStateMap.put(startState, 0);
        inverseStateMap.put(endState, graph.size() - 1);
        
        int stateId = 1;
        
        // Assign indices to hidden states:
        for (HiddenMarkovModelState state : graph) {
            if (!state.equals(startState) && !state.equals(endState)) {
                stateMap.put(stateId, state);
                inverseStateMap.put(state, stateId);
                stateId++;
            }
        }
        
        // Computes the entire Viterbi matrix:
        double[][] viterbiMatrix =
                computeViterbiMatrix(
                        sequence,
                        stateMap,
                        inverseStateMap);
        
        // Uses the dynamic programming result reconstruction:
        return tracebackStateSequenceViterbi(viterbiMatrix,
                                      sequence,
                                      stateMap,
                                      inverseStateMap);
    }
    
    /**
     * Returns the sum of probabilities over all the feasible paths that accord
     * to the {@code sequence}.
     * 
     * @param sequence the sequence text.
     * 
     * @return the sum of probabilities.
     */
    public double runForwardAlgorithm(String sequence) {
        
        // Get all the states reachable from the start state:
        Set<HiddenMarkovModelState> graph = computeAllStates();
        
        if (!graph.contains(endState)) {
            // End state unreachable. Abort.
            throw new IllegalStateException("End state is unreachable.");
        }
        
        // Maps the column index to the corresponding state:
        Map<Integer, HiddenMarkovModelState> stateMap = 
                new HashMap<>(graph.size());
        
        // Maps the state to the corresponding column index:
        Map<HiddenMarkovModelState, Integer> inverseStateMap = 
                new HashMap<>(graph.size());
        
        // Initialize maps for start and end states:
        stateMap.put(0, startState);
        stateMap.put(graph.size() - 1, endState);
        
        inverseStateMap.put(startState, 0);
        inverseStateMap.put(endState, graph.size() - 1);
        
        int stateId = 1;
        
        // Assign indices to hidden states:
        for (HiddenMarkovModelState state : graph) {
            if (!state.equals(startState) && !state.equals(endState)) {
                stateMap.put(stateId, state);
                inverseStateMap.put(state, stateId);
                stateId++;
            }
        }
        
        // Computes the entire forward matrix:
        double[][] forwardMatrix =
                computeForwardMatrix(
                        sequence,
                        stateMap,
                        inverseStateMap);
        
        // Uses the dynamic programming result reconstruction:
        return tracebackStateSequenceForward(forwardMatrix, 
                                             inverseStateMap);
    }
       
    /**
     * Composes a sequence according to this HMM.
     * 
     * @return a sequence.
     */
    public String compose() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        
        HiddenMarkovModelState currentState = startState;
        
        while (true) {
            currentState = doStateTransition(currentState);
            
            if (currentState.equals(endState)) {
                // Once here, we are done:
                return sb.toString();
            }
            
            sb.append(doEmit(currentState));
        }
    }
    
    /**
     * Computes the entire Viterbi matrix.
     * 
     * @param sequence        the input text.
     * @param stateMap        the state map. From column index to the state.
     * @param inverseStateMap the inverse state map. From state to column index.
     * 
     * @return the entire Viterbi matrix.
     */
    private double[][] computeViterbiMatrix(
            String sequence,
            Map<Integer, HiddenMarkovModelState> stateMap,
            Map<HiddenMarkovModelState, Integer> inverseStateMap) {
        
        double[][] matrix = new double[sequence.length() + 1]
                                      [stateMap.size()];
        
        // Set all required cells to unset sentinel:
        for (int rowIndex = 1; rowIndex < matrix.length; rowIndex++) {
            Arrays.fill(matrix[rowIndex], UNSET_PROBABILITY);
        }
        
        // BEGIN: Base case initialization.
        matrix[0][0] = 1.0;
        
        for (int columnIndex = 1; 
                 columnIndex < matrix[0].length;
                 columnIndex++) {
            
            matrix[0][columnIndex] = 0.0;
        }
        // END: Done with the base case initialization.
        
        // Recursively build the matrix:
        for (int h = 1; h < matrix[0].length - 1; h++) {
            matrix[sequence.length()][h] = 
                computeViterbiMatrixImpl(
                        sequence.length(),
                        h,
                        matrix, 
                        sequence, 
                        stateMap,
                        inverseStateMap);
        }
        
        return matrix;
    }
    
    /**
     * Computes the entire forward matrix.
     * 
     * @param sequence        the input text.
     * @param stateMap        the state map. From column index to the state.
     * @param inverseStateMap the inverse state map. From state to column index.
     * 
     * @return the entire Viterbi matrix.
     */
    private double[][] computeForwardMatrix(
            String sequence,
            Map<Integer, HiddenMarkovModelState> stateMap,
            Map<HiddenMarkovModelState, Integer> inverseStateMap) {
        
        double[][] forwardMatrix = new double[sequence.length() + 1]
                                             [stateMap.size()];
        
        // Set all required cells to unset sentinel:
        for (int rowIndex = 1; rowIndex < forwardMatrix.length; rowIndex++) {
            Arrays.fill(forwardMatrix[rowIndex], UNSET_PROBABILITY);
        }
        
        // BEGIN: Base case initialization.
        forwardMatrix[0][0] = 1.0;
        
        for (int columnIndex = 1; 
                 columnIndex < forwardMatrix[0].length;
                 columnIndex++) {
            
            forwardMatrix[0][columnIndex] = 0.0;
        }
        // END: Done with the base case initialization.
        
        // Recursively build the matrix:
        for (int h = 1; h < forwardMatrix[0].length - 1; h++) {
            forwardMatrix[sequence.length()][h] = 
                computeForwardMatrixImpl(
                        sequence.length(),
                        h,
                        forwardMatrix, 
                        sequence, 
                        stateMap,
                        inverseStateMap);
        }
        
        return forwardMatrix;
    }
    
    /**
     * Computes the actual Viterbi matrix.
     * 
     * @param i             the {@code i} variable; the length of the sequence 
     *                      prefix.
     * @param h             the state index.
     * @param viterbiMatrix the actual Viterbi matrix under construction.
     * @param sequence      the symbol sequence.
     * @param stateMap      the map mapping state IDs to states.
     * @return 
     */
    private double computeViterbiMatrixImpl(
            int i,
            int h,
            double[][] viterbiMatrix,
            String sequence,
            Map<Integer, HiddenMarkovModelState> stateMap,
            Map<HiddenMarkovModelState, Integer> inverseStateMap) {
        
        if (viterbiMatrix[i][h] != UNSET_PROBABILITY) {
            return viterbiMatrix[i][h];
        }
        
        final int NUMBER_OF_STATES = stateMap.size();
        
        if (h >= NUMBER_OF_STATES - 1) {
            return UNSET_PROBABILITY;
        }
        
        if (h == 0) {
            return i == 0 ? 1.0 : -1.0;
        }
        
        char symbol = sequence.charAt(i - 1);
        
        HiddenMarkovModelState state = stateMap.get(h);
        double psih = state.getEmissions().get(symbol);
                
        Set<HiddenMarkovModelState> parentStates = state.getIncomingStates();
        
        double maximumProbability = Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY;
        
        for (HiddenMarkovModelState parent : parentStates) {
            double v = 
                    computeViterbiMatrixImpl(
                            i - 1, 
                            inverseStateMap.get(parent),
                            viterbiMatrix, 
                            sequence,
                            stateMap, 
                            inverseStateMap);
            
            v *= parent.getFollowingStates().get(state);
            maximumProbability = Math.max(maximumProbability, v);
        }
        
        viterbiMatrix[i][h] = maximumProbability * psih;
        return viterbiMatrix[i][h];
    }
    
    /**
     * Computes the actual forward matrix.
     * 
     * @param i             the {@code i} variable; the length of the sequence 
     *                      prefix.
     * @param h             the state index.
     * @param forwardMatrix the actual Viterbi matrix under construction.
     * @param sequence      the symbol sequence.
     * @param stateMap      the map mapping state IDs to states.
     * 
     * @return the forward matrix.
     */
    private double computeForwardMatrixImpl(
            int i,
            int h,
            double[][] forwardMatrix,
            String sequence,
            Map<Integer, HiddenMarkovModelState> stateMap,
            Map<HiddenMarkovModelState, Integer> inverseStateMap) {
        
        if (forwardMatrix[i][h] != UNSET_PROBABILITY) {
            return forwardMatrix[i][h];
        }
        
        final int NUMBER_OF_STATES = stateMap.size();
        
        if (h >= NUMBER_OF_STATES - 1) {
            return UNSET_PROBABILITY;
        }
        
        if (h == 0) {
            return i == 0 ? 1.0 : 0.0;
        }
        
        char symbol = sequence.charAt(i - 1);
        
        HiddenMarkovModelState state = stateMap.get(h);
        double psih = state.getEmissions().get(symbol);
                
        Set<HiddenMarkovModelState> parentStates = state.getIncomingStates();
        
        double totalProbability = 0.0;
        
        for (HiddenMarkovModelState parent : parentStates) {
            double f =  
                    computeForwardMatrixImpl(
                            i - 1, 
                            inverseStateMap.get(parent),
                            forwardMatrix, 
                            sequence,
                            stateMap, 
                            inverseStateMap);
            
            f  *= parent.getFollowingStates().get(state);
            totalProbability += f ;
        }
        
        forwardMatrix[i][h] = totalProbability * psih;
        return forwardMatrix[i][h];
    }
    
    private HiddenMarkovModelStatePath 
        tracebackStateSequenceViterbi(
                double[][] viterbiMatrix,
                String sequence,
                Map<Integer, HiddenMarkovModelState> stateMap,
                Map<HiddenMarkovModelState, Integer> inverseStateMap) {
            
        int bottomMaximumIndex = computeBottomMaximumIndex(viterbiMatrix);
        
        HiddenMarkovModelState bottomState = stateMap.get(bottomMaximumIndex);
        
        List<HiddenMarkovModelState> stateList = 
                new ArrayList<>(viterbiMatrix[0].length);
        
        stateList.add(endState);
        
        final int HIGHEST_I = viterbiMatrix.length - 1;
        
        tracebackStateSequenceImpl(viterbiMatrix,
                                   HIGHEST_I, 
                                   bottomState, 
                                   stateList, 
                                   inverseStateMap);
        
        stateList.add(startState);
        
        Collections.reverse(stateList);
        
        return new HiddenMarkovModelStatePath(stateList, sequence, this);
    }
    
    private double 
        tracebackStateSequenceForward(
                double[][] forwardMatrix,
                Map<HiddenMarkovModelState, Integer> inverseStateMap) {
            
        final int ROW_INDEX = forwardMatrix.length - 1;
        
        double probability = 0.0;
        
        Set<HiddenMarkovModelState> parents = endState.getIncomingStates();
        
        for (HiddenMarkovModelState parent : parents) {
            if (parent.equals(startState) || parent.equals(endState)) {
                // Omit the start state:
                continue;
            }
            
            int parentIndex = inverseStateMap.get(parent);
            double p = forwardMatrix[ROW_INDEX][parentIndex];
            p *= parent.getFollowingStates().get(endState);
            probability += p;
        }
        
        return probability;
    }
        
    private void tracebackStateSequenceImpl(
            double[][] viterbiMatrix,
            int i,
            HiddenMarkovModelState state,
            List<HiddenMarkovModelState> stateList,
            Map<HiddenMarkovModelState, Integer> inverseStateMap) {
        
        if (state.equals(startState)) {
            return;
        }
        
        stateList.add(state);
        
        HiddenMarkovModelState nextState = 
                computeNextState(viterbiMatrix, 
                                 i,
                                 state,
                                 inverseStateMap);
        
        tracebackStateSequenceImpl(viterbiMatrix, 
                                   i - 1,
                                   nextState,
                                   stateList,
                                   inverseStateMap);
    }
    
    private HiddenMarkovModelState
         computeNextState(
                 double[][] viterbiMatrix, 
                 int i, 
                 HiddenMarkovModelState state,
                 Map<HiddenMarkovModelState, Integer> inverseStateMap) {
             
        Set<HiddenMarkovModelState> parents = state.getIncomingStates();
        HiddenMarkovModelState nextState = null;
        
        double maximumProbability = Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY;
        
        for (HiddenMarkovModelState parent : parents) {
            int parentIndex = inverseStateMap.get(parent);
            
            double probability = parent.getFollowingStates().get(state);
            probability *= viterbiMatrix[i - 1][parentIndex];
            
            if (maximumProbability < probability) {
                maximumProbability = probability;
                nextState = parent;
            }
        }
        
        return nextState;
    }
        
    private int computeBottomMaximumIndex(double[][] viterbiMatrix) {
        int maximumIndex = -1;
        double maximumProbability = Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY;
        final int ROW_INDEX = viterbiMatrix.length - 1;
        
        for (int i = 1; i < viterbiMatrix[0].length; i++) {
            double currentProbability = viterbiMatrix[ROW_INDEX][i];
            
            if (maximumProbability < currentProbability) {
                maximumProbability = currentProbability;
                maximumIndex = i;
            }
        }
        
        return maximumIndex;
    }
    
    private HiddenMarkovModelState 
        doStateTransition(HiddenMarkovModelState currentState) {
            
        double coin = random.nextDouble();
        
        for (Map.Entry<HiddenMarkovModelState, Double> e 
                : currentState.getFollowingStates().entrySet()) {
            
            if (coin >= e.getValue()) {
                coin -= e.getValue();
            } else {
                return e.getKey();
            }
        }
        
        throw new IllegalStateException("Should not get here.");
    }
    
    private char doEmit(HiddenMarkovModelState currentState) {
        double coin = random.nextDouble();
        
        for (Map.Entry<Character, Double> e 
                : currentState.getEmissions().entrySet()) {
            
            if (coin >= e.getValue()) {
                coin -= e.getValue();
            } else {
                return e.getKey();
            }
        }
        
        throw new IllegalStateException("Should not get here.");
    }
    
    private Set<HiddenMarkovModelState> computeAllStates() {
        Deque<HiddenMarkovModelState> queue = new ArrayDeque<>();
        Set<HiddenMarkovModelState> visited = new HashSet<>();
        
        queue.addLast(startState);
        visited.add(startState);
        
        while (!queue.isEmpty()) {
            HiddenMarkovModelState currentState = queue.removeFirst();
            
            for (HiddenMarkovModelState followerState 
                    : currentState.getFollowingStates().keySet()) {
                
                if (!visited.contains(followerState)) {
                    visited.add(followerState);
                    queue.addLast(followerState);
                }
            }
        }
        
        return visited;
    }
    
    private void depthFirstSearchImpl(
            List<List<HiddenMarkovModelState>> statePaths,
            List<HiddenMarkovModelState> currentPath,
            int expectedStatePathSize,
            HiddenMarkovModelState currentState) {
        
        if (currentPath.size() == expectedStatePathSize) {
            // End recursion. If the current state equals the end state, we have
            // a path:
            if (currentState.equals(endState)) {
                statePaths.add(new ArrayList<>(currentPath));
            }
            
            return;
        }
        
        // For each child, do...
        for (HiddenMarkovModelState followerState 
                : currentState.getFollowingStates().keySet()) {
            
            // Do state:
            currentPath.add(followerState);
            
            // Recur deeper:
            depthFirstSearchImpl(statePaths,
                                 currentPath,
                                 expectedStatePathSize, 
                                 followerState);
            
            // Undo state:
            currentPath.remove(currentPath.size() - 1);
        }
    }
}
```

**`com.github.coderodde.hmm.HiddenMarkovModelState.java:`**

```
package com.github.coderodde.hmm;

import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

/**
 * This class defines the hidden states of a hidden Markov model.
 */
public final class HiddenMarkovModelState {
    
    /**
     * The ID of this state. Used to differentiating between the states.
     */
    private final int id;
    
    /**
     * The state type of this state.
     */
    private final HiddenMarkovModelStateType type;
    
    /**
     * Maps each transition target to the transition probability.
     */
    private final Map<HiddenMarkovModelState, Double> transitionMap =
            new HashMap<>();
    
    /**
     * Holds all incoming states.
     */
    private final Set<HiddenMarkovModelState> incomingTransitions = 
            new HashSet<>();
    
    /**
     * Maps each emission character to its probability. 
     */
    private final Map<Character, Double> emissionMap = new HashMap<>();
    
    public HiddenMarkovModelState(int id, HiddenMarkovModelStateType type) {
        this.id = id;
        this.type = type;
    }
    
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    
    public Map<HiddenMarkovModelState, Double> getFollowingStates() {
        return Collections.unmodifiableMap(transitionMap);
    }
    
    public Map<Character, Double> getEmissions() {
        return Collections.unmodifiableMap(emissionMap);
    }
    
    public Set<HiddenMarkovModelState> getIncomingStates() {
        return Collections.unmodifiableSet(incomingTransitions);
    }
    
    public void normalize() {
        normalizeEmissionMap();
        normalizeTransitionMap();
    }
    
    public void addStateTransition(HiddenMarkovModelState followerState, 
                                   Double probability) {
        if (type.equals(HiddenMarkovModelStateType.END)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    "End HMM states may not have outgoing state transitions.");
        }
        
        transitionMap.put(followerState, probability);
        followerState.incomingTransitions.add(this);
    }
    
    public void addEmissionTransition(Character character, Double probability) {
        switch (type) {
            case START:
            case END:
                throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                        "Start and end HMM states may not have emissions.");
        }
        
        emissionMap.put(character, probability);
    }
    
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        return id == ((HiddenMarkovModelState) o).id;
    }
    
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return id;
    }
    
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("[HMM state, ID = %d, type = %s]", id, type);
    }
    
    private void normalizeTransitionMap() {
        double sumOfProbabilities = computeTransitionProbabilitySum();
        
        for (Map.Entry<HiddenMarkovModelState, Double> e 
                : transitionMap.entrySet()) {
            e.setValue(e.getValue() / sumOfProbabilities);
        }
    }
    
    private void normalizeEmissionMap() {
        double sumOfProbabilities = computeEmissionProbabilitySum();
        
        for (Map.Entry<Character, Double> e : emissionMap.entrySet()) {
            e.setValue(e.getValue() / sumOfProbabilities);
        }
    }
    
    private double computeTransitionProbabilitySum() {
        double sumOfProbabilities = 0.0;
        
        for (Double probability : transitionMap.values()) {
            sumOfProbabilities += probability;
        }
        
        return sumOfProbabilities;
    }
    
    private double computeEmissionProbabilitySum() {
        double sumOfProbabilities = 0.0;
        
        for (Double probability : emissionMap.values()) {
            sumOfProbabilities += probability;
        }
        
        return sumOfProbabilities;
    }
}
```

**`com.github.coderodde.hmm.HiddenMarkovModelStatePath.java:`**

```
package com.github.coderodde.hmm;

import static java.lang.Math.E;
import static java.lang.Math.log;
import static java.lang.Math.pow;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * This class stores the state path over the hidden states of an HMM.
 */
public final class HiddenMarkovModelStatePath 
    implements Comparable<HiddenMarkovModelStatePath> {
    
    private final List<HiddenMarkovModelState> stateSequence;
    private final double probability;
    
    HiddenMarkovModelStatePath(List<HiddenMarkovModelState> stateSequence,
                                   String observedSymbols,
                                   HiddenMarkovModel hiddenMarkovModel) {
        
        this.stateSequence = stateSequence;
        this.probability = computeJointProbability(observedSymbols);
    }
    
    public int size() {
        return stateSequence.size();
    }
    
    public HiddenMarkovModelState getState(int stateIndex) {
        return stateSequence.get(stateIndex);
    }
    
    public double getProbability() {
        return probability;
    }
    
    @Override
    public int compareTo(HiddenMarkovModelStatePath o) {
        return Double.compare(probability, o.probability);
    }
    
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append("[");
        
        boolean first = true;
        
        for (HiddenMarkovModelState state : stateSequence) {
            if (first) {
                first = false;
            } else {
                sb.append(", ");
            }
            
            sb.append(state.getId());
        }
        
        sb.append("| p = ");
        sb.append(probability);
        sb.append("]");
        return sb.toString();
    }
    
    /**
     * Computes the joint probability of this path.
     * 
     * @param observedSymbols the observation text.
     * 
     * @return the joint probability of this path and the input text.
     */
    private double computeJointProbability(String observedSymbols) {
        double logProbability = computeEmissionProbabilities(observedSymbols) +
                                computeTransitionProbabilities();
        
        // Convert to probability:
        return pow(E, logProbability);
    }
    
    /**
     * Computes the product of emission probabilities over the input text.
     * 
     * @param observedSymbols the input text.
     * 
     * @return the total emission probability.
     */
    private double computeEmissionProbabilities(String observedSymbols) {
        double probability = 0.0;
        
        for (int i = 0; i != observedSymbols.length(); i++) {
            char observedSymbol = observedSymbols.charAt(i);
            HiddenMarkovModelState state = stateSequence.get(i + 1);
            probability += log(state.getEmissions().get(observedSymbol));
        }
        
        return probability;
    }
    
    /**
     * Computes the product of transition probabilities over this path.
     * 
     * @return the product of transitions.
     */
    private double computeTransitionProbabilities() {
        double probability = 0.0;
        
        for (int i = 0; i < stateSequence.size() - 1; i++) {
            HiddenMarkovModelState sourceState = stateSequence.get(i);
            HiddenMarkovModelState targetState = stateSequence.get(i + 1);
            probability += log(sourceState.getFollowingStates()
                                          .get(targetState));
        }
        
        return probability;
    }
}
```

**`com.github.coderodde.hmm.demo.HMMDemo.java:`**

```
package com.github.coderodde.hmm.demo;

import com.github.coderodde.hmm.HiddenMarkovModel;
import com.github.coderodde.hmm.HiddenMarkovModelState;
import com.github.coderodde.hmm.HiddenMarkovModelStatePath;
import com.github.coderodde.hmm.HiddenMarkovModelStateType;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

/**
 * This class implements the demonstration of the hidden Markov model.
 */
public final class HMMDemo {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        Random random = new Random(13L);
        
        HiddenMarkovModelState startState = 
                new HiddenMarkovModelState(0, HiddenMarkovModelStateType.START);
        
        HiddenMarkovModelState endState = 
                new HiddenMarkovModelState(3, HiddenMarkovModelStateType.END);
        
        HiddenMarkovModelState codingState = 
                new HiddenMarkovModelState(
                        1,
                        HiddenMarkovModelStateType.HIDDEN);
        
        HiddenMarkovModelState noncodingState = 
                new HiddenMarkovModelState(
                        2,
                        HiddenMarkovModelStateType.HIDDEN);
        
        HiddenMarkovModel hmm = new HiddenMarkovModel(startState, 
                                                      endState,
                                                      random);
        
        // BEGIN: State transitions.
        startState.addStateTransition(noncodingState, 0.49);
        startState.addStateTransition(codingState, 0.49);
        startState.addStateTransition(endState, 0.02);
        
        codingState.addStateTransition(codingState, 0.4);
        codingState.addStateTransition(endState, 0.3);
        codingState.addStateTransition(noncodingState, 0.3);
        
        noncodingState.addStateTransition(noncodingState, 0.3);
        noncodingState.addStateTransition(codingState, 0.35);
        noncodingState.addStateTransition(endState, 0.35);
        // END: State transitions.
        
        // BEGIN: Emissions.
        codingState.addEmissionTransition('A', 0.18);
        codingState.addEmissionTransition('C', 0.32);
        codingState.addEmissionTransition('G', 0.32);
        codingState.addEmissionTransition('T', 0.18);
        
        noncodingState.addEmissionTransition('A', 0.25);
        noncodingState.addEmissionTransition('C', 0.25);
        noncodingState.addEmissionTransition('G', 0.25);
        noncodingState.addEmissionTransition('T', 0.25);
        // END: Emissions.
        
        startState.normalize();
        codingState.normalize();
        noncodingState.normalize();
        endState.normalize();
        
        System.out.println("--- Composing random walks ---");
        
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            int lineNumber = i + 1;
            System.out.printf("%2d: %s\n", lineNumber, hmm.compose());
        }
        
        String sequence = "AGCG";
        
        List<HiddenMarkovModelStatePath> statePathSequences = 
                hmm.computeAllStatePaths(sequence);
        
        System.out.printf("Brute-force path inference for sequence \"%s\", " + 
                          "total probability = %f.\n",
                          sequence,
                          HiddenMarkovModel.sumPathProbabilities(
                                  statePathSequences));
        
        double hmmProbabilitySum = hmm.runForwardAlgorithm(sequence);
        
        System.out.printf("HMM total probability: %f.\n", hmmProbabilitySum);
        System.out.println("Brute-force state paths:");
        
        int lineNumber = 1;
        
        for (HiddenMarkovModelStatePath stateSequence : statePathSequences) {
            System.out.printf("%4d: %s\n", lineNumber++, stateSequence);
        }
    }
}
```

**`com.github.coderodde.hmm.demo.HiddenMarkovModelStateType.java:`**

```
package com.github.coderodde.hmm;

public enum HiddenMarkovModelStateType {
    
    START,
    HIDDEN,
    END;
    
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        switch (this) {
            case START:
                return "S";
                
            case HIDDEN:
                return "H";
                
            case END:
                return "E";
                
            default:
                throw new EnumConstantNotPresentException(
                        HiddenMarkovModelStateType.class, 
                        "Unknown enum constant: " + this);
        }
    }
}
```

## Critique request

Please, tell me anything that comes to mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your repository, you need to de-indent all of `HiddenMarkovModel.java`.

`sumPathProbabilities` can be written in stream form as

```java
double psum = paths.stream()
    .mapToDouble(HiddenMarkovModelStatePath::getProbability)
    .sum();
```

and that function should not accept a `List`; it should accept the more-general `Collection`.

Similarly, the `computeProbabilitySum()` methods can look like

```java
transitionMap.values().stream().reduce(Double::sum).get()
```

The `HiddenMarkovModelStatePath` does not use its last constructor parameter so you should delete that.

Speaking generally, you would benefit from moving to an immutable functional style, but this will not be an easy transition for the code overall. For example, you'll want to avoid functions of the form `loadStateMaps` which mutates its second and third parameters; but this applies in a lot of other situations.

For final members of primitive type like `id` and `type` that also have `get()` accessors, the only reason you'd want to keep the accessor is if it's used in a functional member reference. If there's no functional member reference, delete the accessor. Make the member `public`.

In `HiddenMarkovModelStatePath::toString()`, the `first`/`append(", ")` logic can be cleaned up by using one of the standard `join` collectors.

Rewrite your `StateType` `toString()` switch as

```java
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return switch (this) {
            case START -> "S";
            case HIDDEN -> "H";
            case END -> "E";
        };
    }
```

Note that the default case is not necessary, because there's no way for an already-constructed instance to have a value other than what you've shown.

In your `printf` calls, replace `\n` with `%n` for portability.